# IIS Hosting Error When Updated to dotnet 5.0

Tags: .net, iis, hosting

I dont get it why, when I update, I have this error. I try to add newtonsoft to API project as well. but it does help. The error showed in EventViewer inside windows server 2012 R2

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
```

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection Enable binding redirection please.

Comment: The issue as there seemed to be a mismatch between the version in packages.config and the assembly version. Try to use NuGet to update Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: It’s working fine on debug or release . But when hosting on iis this happend

Comment: Lex Li I tried but not work

Comment: Ding Peng, I  updated , but stil not working. where can I change package.config

Comment: It happends because , i dont know why, but when exporting the version 10 is inside dll project

Comment: What framework did you use before upgrading?

Comment: Newton soft and I need to enable application 32 bit in application pool as well

Comment: I suggest you rebuild the project and redeploy to IIS to see if this issue still exists.

Comment: i rebuild with vs studio. it works. I rebuild with vs code . it doesnot work